# What is the Soul’s journey after death

Tags: atma, rebirth, afterlife

What is the soul’s journey after the death? Where and how long does it travel?

If a person was chanting Lord Rama’s name an hour before all his consciousness shut down and dying, where does his soul go and what will be his journey like? How long does his soul travel around and what places does he visit? Will there be any next birth? Please give me as much information as you can.